# AngularJS: How to inject service to a static member of a regular class

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm using typescript&angularJS for a project and I have a public class (not controller, just a regular class) to hold some enums, is that possible I can instantiate a static member of this class with a service object?

With Controller, it's very easy to use DI of AngularJS to instantiate a service object but for a regular class, I don't know how to do it.

Thanks.

Add code snippet:

```
export public Enums {
    public static serviceObj; //how to instantiate serviceObj with some service?
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're asking but is this what you're looking for?

```
interface ServiceObj {
}

class Enums {
    public static serviceObj : ServiceObj;
}

Enums.serviceObj = [set from some external location]
```

Comment: That's not what I mean, suppose we have already some service defined, in controller we can use dependency injection to inject it, my question is for this service, how can we inject it to initialize serviceObj in Enums.

Comment: You'll want serviceObj to have some typing info on it but you can set/reassign it just like a normal property.

Comment: Can I use injector to do inject in a regular class instead of using new? Basically I want to use angular way to do it.